# Parallel Data Download from Snowflake to Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I have a big table in Snowflake ( 10B records) , which I want to download in Databricks using Snowflakeconnector (spark.read.format("snowflake")). I am trying to apply parallel fetch by means of dividing the table using a date column. For running concurrently, I am using Databrick's concurrent Notebook mechanism. The split code looks something like this

```
val notebooks = Seq(    
NotebookData("my_snowflake_table", 6000,Map("start_date" -> "2022-05-01", "end_date" -> "2022-08-01")),
    NotebookData("my_snowflake_table", 6000,Map("start_date" -> "2022-08-01", "end_date" -> "2022-11-01")),
    NotebookData("my_snowflake_table", 6000,Map("start_date" -> "2022-11-01", "end_date" -> "2022-12-01")))

// Run the notebooks in parallel
val res = parallelNotebooks(notebooks)

Await.result(res, 7200 seconds) // this is a blocking call.
res.value
```

I was expecting horizontal scalability (by the means of autoscaling cluster) with this , however that doesn't seem to be the case. The time taken per split is lot more compared to when run alone. Each split takes around 15 minutes, but when done together, doesn't even complete even in an hour.

Is it because all the splits are running in the same driver, and therefore bandwidth of the driver node could be the bottleneck , also has compounding effect on the overall performance ?

Even more importantly, does this design make sense for how Dtabricks and Snowflake work together ? How else can we download data from Snowflake to Databricks in a faster way ?

Comment: My first question would be why you are trying to download this table to Databricks - what are you going to do with this data that you couldn’t do with it remaining in Snowflake? However, your current process is, presumably, running with a single Snowflake warehouse so you are probably max-ing out it’s resources. I’d try running each concurrent process with its own warehouse, if possible

Comment: You are right, in an ideal state , ETL workloads could be transferred to Snowflake itself. But wanted to speed up the download process in the existing legacy solution. Actually  it's a pretty big warehouse, big userbase connects to it directly, so a single user running couple of parallel sessions should ideally be not a big problem.